# Finding max or min depending an a cell value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell that can be either a Y or N value and depending on that value I need to find the max or min value of some alphanumeric cells. If the cell has a N value then it needs to find the min value and if a Y then find the max value. I was trying to use the NOT function with this formula but it returns an error:

IF(NOT(M741="N"),(NLOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(O743:O745,">"&O743:O745)=0),O743:O745)),(NLOOKUP(2/1(COUNTIF(O743:O745,"<"&O743:O745)=0),O743:O745)))

Is there another way to do something like this?

Comment: Found the typo in the formula. It should be:

IF(NOT(M741="N"),(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(O743:O745,">"&O743:O745)=0),O743:O745)),(LOOKUP(2/1(COUNTIF(O743:O745,"<"&O743:O745)=0),O743:O745)))

Comment: Changed formula to 

=IF(M741="N",(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(O743:O745,"<"&O743:O745)=0),O743:O745)),LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(O743:O745,">"&O743:O745)=0),O743:O745))

and it works now.